# Display all images of a post with a specific thumbnail size

Tags: wordpress, image, post, image-size

I'm using this snippet to display all images of a post:

```
<?php
$argsThumb = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        //echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
                echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'testsize', false, false).'" />';
    }
}
?>
```

And this code to create a custom thumbnail size

```
add_image_size( 'testsize', 400, 400, true );
```

Unfortunately it doesn't output the images at 400px X 400px, the size is just the original size.
(Note: I re-generated the thumbnails and also added new images to a post, but it still didn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:
wp_get_attachment_url() does not accept parameters.
Using wp_get_attachment_image() instead works.

```
<?php
$argsThumb = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null
);
$attachments = get_posts($argsThumb);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        //echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'testsize').'" />';
    }
}
?>
```